# writing mysql function but failed

Tags: mysql

Trying to writing this function in mysql but it is giving error that:

**`Error Code : 1064
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'IF Per='hour' THEN SET t=Price ; END IF;
    IF Per='day' THEN SET t=Price/24; END ' at line 8`**

```
DELIMITER$$
CREATE  FUNCTION PricePerHour (Price REAL, Per VARCHAR(5))  
RETURNS REAL 
DETERMINISTIC

BEGIN 
DECLARE t REAL;
IF Price IS NOT NULL AND Per IS NOT NULL

IF Per='hour' THEN SET t=Price ; END IF;
IF Per='day' THEN SET t=Price/24; END IF;
IF Per='week' THEN SET t=Price/7/24; END IF;
IF Per='month' THEN SET t=Price/30/24; END IF;
IF Per='year' THEN SET t=Price/365/30/24; END IF;

RETURN t;
END IF;
END $$
DELIMITER;
```

any help should be appreciated. Thanx in advance.

Comment: removed the tag of sql server as this post had nothing to do with ms sql

Answer (score 2, accepted):

missing THEN ?

```
DELIMITER$$
CREATE  FUNCTION PricePerHour (Price REAL, Per VARCHAR(5))  
RETURNS REAL 
DETERMINISTIC

BEGIN 
DECLARE t REAL;
IF Price IS NOT NULL AND Per IS NOT NULL   **THEN**

IF Per='hour' THEN SET t=Price ; END IF;
IF Per='day' THEN SET t=Price/24; END IF;
IF Per='week' THEN SET t=Price/7/24; END IF;
IF Per='month' THEN SET t=Price/30/24; END IF;
IF Per='year' THEN SET t=Price/365/30/24; END IF;

RETURN t;
END IF;
END $$
DELIMITER;
```